# Asp.net's LoggedInTemplate never displays, only AnonymousTemplate

Tags: asp.net

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 to build a website. I want the master page to be slightly different depending on whether one is logged in or not. To this end I use the `<LoggedInTemplate>` and `<AnonymousTemplate>`. Similarly to the unanswered question at [LoggedInTemplate Not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18624055/loggedintemplate-not-displayed), however, currently the latter is always displayed, regardless of whether or not I'm logged in. My code at the master page is as follows:

```
        <asp:LoginView ID="LoginView2" runat="server">
        <LoggedInTemplate>
            <ul id="Loggedin">
                <li><asp:LoginName ID="LoginName1" runat="server"/>User page</li>
                <li><asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" /><a href="Logout.aspx">Log out</a></li>
            </ul>
        </LoggedInTemplate>
        <AnonymousTemplate>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Registration.aspx">Register</a></li>
                <li><a href="Login.aspx">Log in</a></li>
            </ul>
        </AnonymousTemplate>
        </asp:LoginView>
```

My master page's .cs page currently does not contain any code (except for the default lines created at page creation). Does `<LoggedInTemplate>` require code in the associated .cs to work? And if so, what does it need?

My logout page, which behaves differently based on whether one is logged in or not (log out and display page if logged in; redirect to the login page if not logged in), works fine as far as I have been able to tell, suggesting to me that the login procedure works fine. This is as sure as I'm about the login procedure, so if `<LoggedInTemplate>` does not require code in the .cs file, I'll post the code on the login and logout pages to see if there could be a problem there.

Update: The code in the Login.aspx.cs file is

```
    protected void LoginButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationsConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open(); 
    string checkuser = "select count(*) from RegistrationData where UserName='" + UserNameLogin.Text + "' "; 
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(checkuser, conn);
    int temp = Convert.ToInt32(com.ExecuteScalar().ToString());
    conn.Close();
    if (temp == 1)
    {
        conn.Open();
        string checkPassword = "select password from RegistrationData where UserName='" + UserNameLogin.Text + "' ";
        SqlCommand passCom = new SqlCommand(checkPassword, conn);
        string password = passCom.ExecuteScalar().ToString().Replace(" ", "");
        if (password == PasswordLogin.Text)
        {
            Session["New"] = UserNameLogin.Text;
            Response.Redirect ("Default.aspx");
        }
        else Response.Write("Password is incorrect");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("User does not exist");
    }

}
```

For clarity, my Web.Config (just automatically generated code) is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>

    <configuration>

    <connectionStrings>
    <add name="mwd" connectionString="Data Source=P425\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=mwd;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
    <add name="RegistrationsConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Registrations.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
    <system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    </system.web>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>

</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to get `<LoggedInTemplate>` it to work by adding

```
  <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx"></forms>
  </authentication>
```

to the Web.Config file within the `<system.web>` tag and replacing

```
    Session["New"] = UserNameLogin.Text;
    Response.Redirect ("Default.aspx");
```

with

```
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(UserNameLogin.Text, false);
```

and adding `using System.Web.Security;` in the Login.aspx.cs file.

This does break my Logout.aspx page, but that'll probably be easy enough to fix.

Answer (score 0):

what you have in the autentication mode on your webconfig file?

Try similar to this:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms name="test" loginUrl="Login.aspx" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" cookieless="UseCookies" path="/"></forms>
</authentication>
```

Another way to check if you are getting the username using the User.Identity.Name, you can debug that in the code behind of the master page.

Comment: My web.config file has been automatically generated by Visual Studio. It contains the code below. Wherever I try to put in your suggested code, it gives an error.

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0"?>

<configuration>

    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="mwd" connectionString="Data Source=P425\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=mwd;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
        <add name="RegistrationsConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Registrations.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
            providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>`

Comment: `<system.web>
      <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.1" />
      <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.1" />
    </system.web>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None" />
  </appSettings>

</configuration>`

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the asp:LoginStatus outside of your template. That way you will know for sure what is your logged in status.

Also as mentioned previously, you can detect if your user is authenticated by the IsAuthenticated property of Page.

Comment: If I place the asp:LoginStatus above the `<LoggedInTemplate>`, after the asp:LoginView it gives a parser error, and before it another kind of error.

Comment: No error is generated on the default page if I place a `<form id="form1" runat="server">` before the asp:LoginStatus placed before the asp:LoginView, but then the login page generates an error, because 'there may only be one form label for the server side'. Yet, if I delete that tag from the login page, it generates another error. Trying to enclose the entire master page's body in the form tag does not solve it. Any ideas?

Comment: By enclosing the entire content of the body of the master page (which contains the `<asp:ContentPlaceHolder>`) within `<form runat="server"></form>` and removing that tag from the login page, I no longer get an error. However, the login page stops working. I can still enter username and password, but now nothing happens when clicking the login button.

Comment: Apparently, the problem was that I had other form tags on my master page. However, the original problem still exists: What gets displayed is the same regardless of whether I'm logged in.